# Android - Camera with double click

Tags: android, camera

Below are the important stuff. The problem is: I have the camera take a picture when I tap on the surface and store the image to the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital). If I click two or more times before the camera stores the picture, the camera freezes and the phone need a restart. I think I have all the release stuff correct. I even implemented a boolean `onProgress` to take some action, but it seems it doesn't work.

```
public void onClick() {
    if(!onProgress)
    mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
}

Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
        onProgress=true;
        if (imageData != null) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                        "/sdcard/Deltio1.jpg");
                Bitmap e = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                        imageData.length);
                e.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, out);
                out.close();
                Intent i = new Intent(ACT, MediaSend.class);
                ACT.startActivity(i);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast
                .makeText(
                        CON,
                        "???ß??µa st?? ap????e?s?.?eßa???e?te ?t? ??ete sdcard e??atest?µ???",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ACT.finish();
            }

            // FileUtilities.StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData,
            // 50, "ImageName");

            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            onProgress=false;

            // setResult(FOTO_MODE,mIntent);
            // finish();
        }
    }
};
```

You can refer to [the entire code](http://www.copypastecode.com/33005/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `onProgress` flag. You should set it to true at

```
public void onClick() {
        if(!onProgress){
                     **onProgress = true;** 
           mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
                  }

    }
```

Usually, there is a delay of atleast 300-500 milliseconds between the `takePicture()` and `PictureCallback` because Camera sensor has to:
1. Perform Autofocus operation
2. Stop the preview
3. Capture the preview data
4. Encode the raw data
5. AND Fianlly call PictureCallback method.

Regards,
Anirudh.

Comment: didn't know that. Thank you it worked.Also do you know any sample code with camera flash and autofocus?

Comment: There's an autofocus code in the API Demos itself. Usually, flash support varies from device to device as the sensor and the chipset have to support it. I think its a bit difficult to get hold of that code.